# rewriting LEFT OUTER JOIN as a subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, outer-join

Is it possible to rewrite the following left join:

```
SELECT wanted.id AS wanted_id, offers.id AS offer_id, departure_city,
departure_country, destination_city, destination_country, departure_date_min, departure_date_max, MIN(price) as price
FROM wanted LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, wanted_id, SUM(price) AS price FROM `offers` GROUP BY offer_date) AS offers ON wanted.id = offers.wanted_id
WHERE wanted.id IN (SELECT wanted_id FROM wanted_by_user WHERE user_ID=%d) group by offer_id
```

as a subquery?
I have tried it like this, and technically, it works fine, BUT: it only works like an inner join would (meaning not showing rows if there's no match in the table 'offers'):

```
FROM wanted, (SELECT id, SUM(price) AS price FROM `offers` GROUP BY offer_date) AS offers "
    ."WHERE wanted.id IN(SELECT wanted_id FROM wanted_by_user WHERE user_ID=%s)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Second, explain what you mean.  Your query already has a subquery along with the `LEFT JOIN`, so what are you really trying to do.  And, as a simple rule, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: what do you mean "never use commas"? How else should I select more than one table in the FROM clause? To answer your first question: my understanding is that subqueries are an alternative way to joins, easier to read some would argue

Comment: Always use explicit `JOIN` syntax, as you have done in the first query.  This has been ANSI standard syntax for decades, and it is more powerful than using commas.

Comment: You are mixing implicit (inner) joins (in the `where` clause) and explicit `JOIN` operators. Don't do that.

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN` needs an `ON ...` clause. and an alias / correlation name for the subquery, for the outer query to be able to refer to it. That's all.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: thanks, but isn't there quite a debate about subqueries vs. joins going on? My understanding is that there isn't such a clear winner as you made it sound?

Comment: @user5355646 : there is no "winner" . There are only losers, and the biggest loser is the human reader.

Comment: @wildplasser: sorry I don't get it, my LEFT JOIN does have an ON clause? My question was, how can I achieve the same result WITHOUT the JOIN clause and the subquery instead?

Comment: ... which proves that your query is unreadable. *Please* format your query.

Comment: Regarding "*isn't there quite a debate about subqueries vs. join*" - no there isn't. Any decent query optimizer will re-write one into the other _if_ they are equivalent (and the "other" version would be faster). Which brings us back to the question: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: thanks for the insight, I'm using MySQL 5.6....so if I understand you correctly, ideally I would wanna run both query variants and go for the one that is faster, correct?